# Find, Replace and Append new dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

My goal is to go through a table and append a new `<tr>` with the same data as it's previous sibling but with some altered content text.

A section of my html is as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td><label>Share - Spanish</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="blog_share_es" name="blog_share_es" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
```

Within my current function in Javascript the `$(this)` is the `<label>` tag. I have successfully taken the word "Spanish" and replaced it with "Italian" with the following:

```
    var italian = $(this).text().replace("Spanish", "Italian");
```

and then append it to the table as follows:

```
var parentDiv = $(this).parent().parent();
$('<tr><td><label>'+italian+'</label></td><td><input type="text" id="logout_de" name="logout_de" size="30"/></td></tr>').insertAfter(parentDiv);
```

How do I now select the `<input>` and replace all instances of "_es" within the `id` and `name` with "_it" so that I get the following output in html (getting the formatting of the html is not necessary but would be optimal!):

```
<tr>
  <td><label>Share - Italian</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="blog_share_it" name="blog_share_it" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you show what you're doing, or expect to happen, that initiates these actions? Ideally a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, to reproduce your problem/use-case. Incidentally, a `<label>` should identify a specific `<input>` element, please [use the `for` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html) to associate a given `<label>` with the relevant `<input>`.

Comment: @DavidThomas [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r07nvd1k/)

Answer (score 1):

Turned into a plug-in

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmghdtt8/)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.newRow = function (language, suffix) {
        $lastSibling = this.find("tr").last().clone();
        $label = $lastSibling.find("label");
        $labelText = $label.text();
        $label.text($labelText.replace($labelText.substring($labelText.indexOf("- ") + 2), language));
        $input = $lastSibling.find("input");
        $id = $input.attr("id");
        $name = $input.attr("name");
        $input.attr("id", $id.replace($id.substring($id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1), suffix))
              .attr("name", $name.replace($name.substring($name.lastIndexOf("_") + 1), suffix));
        this.find("tbody").append($lastSibling);
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#yourTable").newRow("Italian", "it");
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer! 

Although it doesn't work exactly for my use case, I was able to alter it and have it fit my code.

In my case there are many tables, each one with multiple `<tr>` that contain "Spanish" in them. I did actually want the new row to be appended after _every_ instance of a Spanish row, and not at the end of table altogether.

Comment: also, could you possibly explain the `(function ($){})(jQuery);` What exactly is the `$` and `jQuery` doing?

Comment: Good to hear you have it sorted out. `(function ($){})(jQuery)` is a self-executing anonymous that is usually used when creating a jQuery plugin. It just means that `$` is an alias for `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

something like this... not sure if it 100% works, but gives you right direction

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(input) {
    if (input.attr('id').match(/_it/))
        input.attr('id', input.attr('id').replace(/_it/, '_es');
    if (input.attr('name').match(/_it/))
        input.attr('name', input.attr('name').replace(/_it/, '_es');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the input starting from `$(this)` you have to use the function `find()`, and then you can change the attributes using the function `attr()`

```
var inp = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type=text]");
inp.attr("id", inp.attr("id").replace("_es","_it"));
inp.attr("name", inp.attr("name").replace("_es","_it"));
```